# ProductId for In-App Purchase in WebView

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

I'd like to use In-App Purchase in my iOS app, and want to use product ID in webView.
(html is on server, not local content.)

Is this design likely to be rejected by Apple?

Comment: Is it a hybrid app?

Comment: @Poles No,it's a native app.

Comment: Is the html is only for display purpose? I don't think it will be rejected.

Comment: @Poles Thank you for your answer!  Yes,html is only for display.(I was wondering if the UI for billing can be changed on the server if it is permitted...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it would tend to be a concern during the App Store submission review as the guidelines say no external links or redirections during the payment process with IAP for digital content business.